# Change name & menu_name for Profile in the default menu, w/o altering core files?

Tags: menus, admin-menu

I want to change the name and menu_name of the profile menu in the default menu without altering the core files.

Comment: could you clarify- do you want to change Profile in the admin menu / on the admin page?

Comment: @Milo that is correct, When authors log in, instead of seeing Profile/Your Profile, I want to change it to Account/Your Account. This would appear to be a subtle difference but I'm using a custom post type "Profile" to mimic the profile function on the old site, and this may cause some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could filter gettext to change it. Note that this will change every translatable instance of "Profile".

```
function change_admin_profile_to_account( $thename ){
    $thename = str_replace( 'Profile', 'Account', $thename );
    return $thename;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_admin_profile_to_account' );
```